# Sun Grid Engine finished job info

Tags: jobs, sungridengine

Is there a way to list the node which executed a Sun Grid Engine job using qstat or other SGE commands?

I have to get this information using a python script. I have figured out how to execute SGE commands from python but I didn't find the solution to list the execution node for a particular job. I have tried to list finished jobs using

```
qstat -s z -f -F
```

but the name of the host which executed the job dosen't appear in this list. Anyone could help me please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have your job id

```
qacct -j {job id}
```

Otherwise you can list recents jobs

```
qacct -j -b {YYYYMMDDHHmm}
```

The node that executed the job is the value under the key "hostname".

Comment: -o (job owner) flag is a good thing one may want to add, on my cluster it lists jobs of all users otherwise